# Substring in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I am starting SQL and I have the following query

```
Select * from Material where theme = 'math' or name = 'math';
```

As far as I know this gets me the values that actually have that exact string 'math' on the theme or on the name. How do I put it if I want that value i.e 'math' also as a substring of the attributes theme or name.

Comment: The functionality you are looking for is `like`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest method is to use a wildcard match using the `LIKE` operator:

```
 WHERE theme LIKE '%math%'  // math appears anywhere in the string
 WHERE theme LIKE 'math%'   // math appears at the START of the string
 WHERE theme LIKE '%math'   // math appears at the END of the string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from Material where theme LIKE '%math%' or name LIKE '%math%';
```

I believe you are interested in using the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I thought I had to use something like SUBSTRING();

Comment: Well you shouldn't look at it like substring, because you're not trying to extract a portion of a string. You are simply trying to match a portion of the string. Which is why LIKE is what you want oppose to substring